# Flutter: ListWheelScrollView magnifier not working

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart

The magnifier of the ListWheelScrollView is empty (just a white container)

```dart
ListWheelScrollView(
  itemExtent: 60,
  magnification: 2,
  useMagnifier: true,
  children: List.generate(
     100,
      (index) => Card(
          key: ValueKey(index),
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(index.toString()),
          ))).toList(),
),
```

What am I doing wrong?
(No errors are shown when running `flutter run -v` and `flutter doctor -v` finds no issues)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `Container` instead of `Card` and set horizontal `padding` for it:

```
ListWheelScrollView(
  itemExtent: 60,
  magnification: 1.5,
  useMagnifier: true,
  squeeze: 0.7,
  children: List.generate(
    100,
    (index) => Container(
      key: ValueKey(index),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(index.toString()),
      ),
    )).toList(),
),
```

Result:

[image: res]

2. Instead of using `ListTile` and horizontal `padding`, you can put the text inside a `Center` widget that is placed directly inside the `Container`:

```
ListWheelScrollView(
  itemExtent: 60,
  magnification: 1.5,
  useMagnifier: true,
  squeeze: 0.7,
  children: List.generate(
    100,
    (index) => Container(
      key: ValueKey(index),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(index.toString()),
      ),
    )).toList(),
),
```

Result:

[image: res2]